# mysql connection exception Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

This is bit of wired problem.I have two server A and B, and mysql was installed on server A,then give privilege to B using `mysql>grant all privileges on dbname.* to user1@BserverIP identified by 'pass';flush privileges;` and from B, I can use command `mysql -h B -u xx -p'xx'` connect to mysql on A server. But from project view, the error errors:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

In project properties file, the configuration as below:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://B server ip:3306/dbname
username=user1
password=pass
```

So anybody can help ?

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but I think it's `flush privileges`, plural, with an "s" at the end